# Incorporating observation weights in the randomForest package

Tags: r, random-forest

How can I use the R `randomForest` package with observation weights? I know that there is no such option in this package. I have 2 questions:

1. Are there any solutions to this problem using `randomForest` package? At this moment I'm drawing samples from data with weights as the probability so I can at least simulate it:

   ```
   m = dim(data)[1]
   sample(data, m, replace=TRUE, prob=weights)
   ```

   It works are there other (better) solutions?
2. Are there any alternatives to the `randomForest` package. I found the `party` package (cforest) but it's terrible in terms of memory management (or I cannot use it the way I use `randomForest` package). I have around 200k observations and 30-40 variables.

EDIT:

Sorry for not clarifying details. I'm using the `randomForest` package for regression problem (not classification). It is a time series and every observation has its weight. Later on this weight is used to determine the model performance across test observations. The y variable is continuous.

Comment: Might find more interest at http://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same option as you Pawel in the Random Forest. And I figured out the package "ranger" in R incorporates it in the function "ranger" (through the parameter "case.weights").

The package released in june 2016 so it is very young.

Best,

Comment: I just figured out randomForestSRC also included a case.wt parameter in its release 2.2.0.

See `rfsrc.news()` with a recent version of randomForestSRC installed ! 

This solution may be safer since randomForestSRC is a widely used package !
Best,

Answer (score 2):

`randomForest` does have a "classwt" parameter that should allow you to account for differential sampling probabilities or even for differential costs. Admittedly it is ignored with regression  Perhaps you should explain *why* you need to use weighting and what sort of y variable you are using.